# Thumbnail not showing in Ionic/typescript app

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am having real trouble getting the thumbnail to show in an Ionic app. I've tried to emulate it on an android device, no go, I've tried to launch the app on my phone, also no go. I tried varying the src parameter in the `[ion-img]`, and that didn't work. So I thought I would ask Stack Overflow.

The Ionic app is a simple one. I basically have a homepage.html and ts file. The app runs one in every way except that it is not displaying the thumbnail. I have the relevant ts code looking like the following:

```
 async startRecord(){
    console.log("Entering record x");
      let base64 = null;
    const option: CaptureVideoOptions = {
      limit: 1,
      duration: 5,
      quality: 100
    };
    var dateObj = new Date();
    var minutes = dateObj.getMinutes().toString();
    let minStr = "";

    if(minutes.length<=1){
      minStr = "0" + minutes;
    }
    else{
      minStr = minutes;
    }
    var date = "Date: " + dateObj.getMonth() + "-" +  dateObj.getDate() + "-" + dateObj.getFullYear() + " Time: " + dateObj.getHours() + ":" + minStr;
    console.log("date",date);
    const id:string = uuid();

    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(option).then(async (mediaFile: MediaFile[]) => {
      this.video = mediaFile[0];
      this.keys = Object.keys(this.video);
   
      await this.createThumbnail(this.video?.fullPath);
      const video = {
        id: id,
        fullPath: this.video?.fullPath,
        name: this.video?.name,
        userLabel: 'undecided',
        thumbnail: this.thumbnail,
        serverLabel: "none",
        size: this.video?.size,
        dateVideoTaken: date,
      };
      console.log(video);
      await this.util.storeVide(video);
      await this.getAllVideos();
    }, (error: CaptureError) => {
      console.log(error.code);
      alert(error.code);
    });
  }
```

I call the `createThumbnail` from video-capture, and that also seems to run fine. I'm using the console.log to verify that the thumbnail is successfully been created on my emulator or phone, and it is.

```
async createThumbnail(path){
    console.clear();
    console.log('Full Video Path ', path);
    var numstr = new Date().getTime();
    var option:CreateThumbnailOptions = {fileUri: path ,width:160, height:206, atTime:1, outputFileName: 'thumbnail' + numstr, quality:100 };
    const thumbnail = await this.VideoEditor.createThumbnail(option);
    console.log("Thumbnail desc.", thumbnail);
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
  }
```

I check the thumbnail by physically going to the location on my phone, and the image is indeed there. I then try to represent it as a thumbnail for this particular video, using this text in the HTML page:

```
          <ion-thumbnail slot="start" class="customized-image" id="thumbnail" (click)="openVideo(video.fullPath)" > 
                <!-- <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y"> -->
                <img src="{{video?.thumbnail}}">
          </ion-thumbnail>
```

This works fine when I call a generic thumbnail from gravatar but somehow fails when calling the thumbnail.

I tried mixing this problem all day yesterday and thought I would ask the Stack Overflow community.

Please feel free to ask for more code If this doesn't describe my problem well enough.

Also, the f key no longer works on my computer, hence the misspellings in my text. I have to copy-paste the key when I want to use it.

Here is a console log sample:

[image: Console Log]

Comment: What is the value of `video?.thumbnail` if you console.log it?

Comment: Hi Suraj. I included a sample video object. I checked on my phone, and the thumbnail does exist at this location.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Try setting `file://` before the thumbnail path

Comment: Hi Suraj. I am sorry or the long delays, this is or a personal project and I work during the day. I tried setting the thumbnail path to file:// and ile:/// but both did not work. I did this by appending to the thumbnail path: thumbnail: 'file:///' + this.thumbnail, but it did not work.

Comment: And I'm sorry that I posted an image it my computer is broken, I'll have to get a new one but I'm working with this one in the interim. I can't select from the cmd because some keys are continuously pressed, making selecting text impossible.